# TextField and Submit JavaFx for Hangman game

Tags: java, javafx

How to make TextField that inputs letter than compares it with string? It's Hangman game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field itself would not do any of the comparing, it will act **only** as an input access point. That would mean that the only thing it will do is gather whatever you type in it.

So how do you actually make the comparison? Well you will have to call an underlying method, every time there is something written in the field.

for that method you could use some of Java's build in String functionalities for example you could use:

```
string.indexOf('a').
```

> If the `a` is present in string, it returns the `index(>=0)`. If not, it returns `-1`. So, a non-negative return value means that `a` is present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Swing to create the UI.
There is a TextBox (JTextField). But mostly the Textbox itself will not write anything in it. A user has to do the writing.
You would like to make it only possible to add one char at a time or you have to check if the text the user entered is at most one char.
After that you can check if the char exists in the word you are looking for.